# How to send data from slack to another service?

Tags: api, redmine, slack-api

I'm looking for how to send data from a Slack Channel with a message like :

@Slackbot :create ticket: "Check apache configuration settings"

to my redmine API instance ??

It is possible ?

I know that is possible with the webhooks to send into Slack chan, but to the reverse ??

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Slash Command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) but may need a server that can forward the request to redmine or use an [Outgoing Webhook](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks).  You're question is pretty generic so may need to be more specific to avoid getting a downvote.